# convert microsoft documents into pdf with nodejs

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdf-generation, ms-office

DO you know any library to convert Microsoft Office documents like Word (.doc) or Excel (xlsx) into PDF using NodeJS? I have been looking around with no luck.
Thanks

Comment: Any solutions so far?

Comment: There is now https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nativedocuments/docx-wasm for doc/docx (not Excel files)

Answer (score 11):

Well, I think the best possible converting option would be using the LibreOffice headless command line option.

`libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf *.odt`

So if you want to call from Node.js, you have to wrap the command line call into child process http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: Couldn't find libreoffice command in windows. soffice seems to be the correct command located at C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program