# Node.js Convert Docx to PDF: soffice binary

Tags: node.js, pdf, doc

I am referring to this answer to convert the docx file to PDF using libreoffice-convert.
[Nodejs: Convert Doc to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347159/nodejs-convert-doc-to-pdf)

Having below errors:

```
OperationalError: Could not find soffice binary
    at /Users/Documents/Innovation/node-server-tutorial/node_modules/libreoffice-convert/index.js:36:41
    at /Users/Documents/Innovation/node-server-tutorial/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3377:9
    at /Users/Documents/Innovation/node-server-tutorial/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:473:16
    at iteratorCallback (/Users/Documents/Innovation/node-server-tutorial/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1064:13)
    at /Users/Documents/Innovation/node-server-tutorial/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:969:16
    at /Users/Documents/Innovation/node-server-tutorial/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3369:13
    at /Users/Documents/Innovation/node-server-tutorial/node_modules/libreoffice-convert/index.js:33:68
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:154:23) {

}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this one another SOF page.

> first LibreOffice must installed in your system, then set environment path for 'soffice' command.after complete these steps you can simply run above lines. –
> nadgeSachin

[Nodejs: Convert Doc to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347159/nodejs-convert-doc-to-pdf)